# Match special account names (dev-, ad-, sa-, etc.) with user samAccountName in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and need to search for special accounts like a developer (dev-) or admin (ad-), strip the prefix off and see if that user has an account (sAMAccountName)

Below, I am able to serach and get all the special account from my domain, but I need to script the entire process so I only get back the special accounts that do not have regular user accounts.

```
ForEach ($acct in "Dev-*","dev-*","rl-*","cafe-*","dev-dev-*","ad-*", `
    "sa-*","AD-*","ir-*","tst-*","o365-*","te-*","la-*","vmtest-*", `
    "mtep-*","EIM-*","GRT*","cbl-","DS-*","fim-*") { 
        Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -like $acct} -SearchBase "DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=com" `
        -Properties sAMAccountName | Select sAMAccountName 
}
```

Comment: Just so I understand, you may have an account "dev-jbloggs" but you only want to return it if there is no account "jbloggs"?

Comment: Just a note, but sAMAccountName is not a case-sensitive field.  `"Dev-*"` and `"dev-*"` should return identical results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty, but you could remove the prefix for the username that you find and search for that user. If nothing returns (no match), continue with the dev-account, else drop it. Ex:

```
ForEach ($acct in "Dev-*","dev-*","rl-*","cafe-*","dev-dev-*","ad-*", "sa-*","AD-*","ir-*","tst-*","o365-*","te-*","la-*","vmtest-*", "mtep-*","EIM-*","GRT*","cbl-*","DS-*","fim-*") { 
    Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -like $acct} -SearchBase "DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=com" |
    Where-Object {
        $prefix = $acct.Replace("*","")
        $user = $_.sAMAccountName.Replace($prefix,"")
        if(-not(Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $user} -SearchBase "DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=com")) { 
            #Throw user further down the pipeline
            $_
        }
    } |
    Select sAMAccountName 
}
```

Comment: That's all I was going to suggest. There's not really any other way of doing it AFAIK, however for performance you should only run Get-ADUser once and save it to a variable rather than drag every user down for each $acct.

Comment: I would've saved the prefixes to an array, generated a filter scriptblock with `-or ... -or... ` etc., but that's another question (optimization) :-)